# Android notification shown only icon on status bar

Tags: android

In my application i wrote simple notification function, the method shows icon only on status bar and i want to show notification layout too, but not shown automatically and i have pull down android status bar down to see that,

```
public static void createNotification(Context context, Class activity, String title, String subject, int count_unread_message) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subject)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setNumber(count_unread_message)
            .setPriority(0)

            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NOTIFICATIONMANAGER = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NOTIFICATIONMANAGER.notify(159753456, notify);
}
```

It seems this problem is for android 6 and above

Answer (score 4):

For me this was solved by calling `setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)` on the builder.  Hope that helps,

Paul

Comment: in my case it was needed both deprecated methods #setDefaults() and #setPriority()

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that the notification banner is not being displayed, right? So the user must lower the status bar in order to see the notification.

For me what solved it was to set a higher priority to the notification. In your case you should set it to high or max (since it is already on 0 - default):

```
            .setPriority(1)//1 is high, 2 is max
```

Reference: [NotificationCompat.Builder documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPriority(int))

Comment: in my case it was needed both deprecated methods #setDefaults() and #setPriority()

Answer (score 2):

Add `setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)` on the Builder of Notification works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.setLargeIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)` in your code

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.yourIcon);

 Notification notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(subject)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)//can set only bitmap images convert your drawable to bitmap
            .setNumber(count_unread_message)
            .setPriority(0)

            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#largeIcon

Comment: are you sure problem is setting large icon? i get this error:  `Error:(224, 39) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Bitmap`

Comment: dont resolve problem, i dont see notification and only can show small notification icon on status bar, i tested on android 6.0.1, is it cause of this problem? or any permission must be set?

Comment: .setLargeIcon(icon) is deprecated in sdk v23, may be it won't work in android 6.0.1 please check the documentation link above

Comment: on notification layout `setLargeIcon` work fine but I'm not sure problem is `setLargeIcon`

Comment: Hi i see my edited post by you thanks , you dont understand my mean sir, i edited that again. please read again sir :) problem is shown only icon on status bar, i want to show layout too

Comment: I've had setDefaults and setPriority, but notification was still appearing only in Status Bar. Setting Large Icon helped me.